# Is there a tool to query FAT filesystem details?

Tags: filesystems

What filesystem tool could I use, to display details of a FAT volume?

I have no lost data, I need no information forensics level details, and I do not require to alter anything on the FAT volume. I just wish to print out data like:

- the FAT type used on that volume (FAT12, FAT16, FAT32),
- number of File Allocation Tables used on the volume,
- number of bytes per sector,
- bytes per cluster block-size,
- sectors per cluster,
- limit for the number of root directory entries.

FAT64 (a.k.a ExFAT) support would be nice.
Anything available on FreeBSD, Linux, MacOS X, or Windows is fine.

My attempts for web-serching on the topic yield false positives, resulting mostly on tools for overweight people (the word FAT) and instructables on how to format FAT volumes of any size or how to grow a FAT volume. Also found some github projects for manipulating FAT filesystem images, but they do not display the details I am after, instead they allow data recovery or filesystem changes. Fsutil on Windows and gpart on FreeBSD does not provide the FAT details I am after (or at least I did not find how it would do so).

If you know of any built-in OS tool or third party utility that provides the above FAT details, please give me a pointer!

Comment: In Windows, MSINFO32 does the job just fine.

Comment: Thanks @John for pointing out msinfo32.exe! It shows FAT type, and does not show any of the other details I am after. But it is a useful tool nontheless, and very much at hand. And I did not remember I have this at my disposal on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dosfstools on Linux has `fsck.fat` (possibly called `fsck.vfat` in older versions of the package) which shows similar information to chkdsk on MS-DOS:

```
# fsck.fat -v -n /dev/sda1
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkfs.fat"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
       512 bytes per logical sector
      4096 bytes per cluster
        32 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 16384 (sector 32)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
    524288 bytes per FAT (= 1024 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 1064960 (sector 2080)
    130812 data clusters (535805952 bytes)
63 sectors/track, 255 heads
      2048 hidden sectors
   1048576 sectors total
/dev/sda1: 8 files, 1341/130812 clusters
```

GNU mtools is from the era where you'd dual-boot Linux with MS-DOS, and so it has this thing about insisting on DOS-style drive letters (which have to be defined beforehand in `/etc/mtools.conf`). The -i option `minfo -i /dev/sdb1 ::` may work though.

```
# cat /etc/mtools.conf
drive a: file="/dev/sda1" exclusive
drive b: file="/dev/sdb1" exclusive

# minfo -v b:
device information:
===================
filename="/dev/sdb1"
sectors per track: 63
heads: 255
cylinders: 66

media byte: f8

mformat command line: mformat -T 1048576 -h 255 -s 63 -H 0 b:

bootsector information
======================
banner:"mkfs.fat"
sector size: 512 bytes
cluster size: 8 sectors
reserved (boot) sectors: 32
fats: 2
max available root directory slots: 0
small size: 0 sectors
media descriptor byte: 0xf8
sectors per fat: 0
sectors per track: 63
heads: 255
hidden sectors: 2048
big size: 1048576 sectors
physical drive id: 0x80
reserved=0x0
dos4=0x29
serial number: 3F14F81D
disk label="NO NAME    "
disk type="FAT32   "
Big fatlen=1024
Extended flags=0x0000
FS version=0x0000
rootCluster=2
infoSector location=1
backup boot sector=6

Infosector:
signature=0x41615252
free clusters=130811
last allocated cluster=2
```

exFAT is not "aka" FAT64. (Microsoft, the authors, have named it "exFAT" – it is therefore "exFAT".) It's different enough from the original FATs to have not only its own name but different tools as well.

There are two Linux toolsets for exFAT – exfat-utils (older, part of the free FUSE-based driver) and exfatprogs (newer, maintained by Samsung I believe).

exfat-utils has `dumpexfat`:

```
$ dumpexfat /tmp/exfat.img
Volume label
Volume serial number      0x765cf1c4
FS version                       1.0
Sector size                      512
Cluster size                    4096
Sectors count                 262144
Free sectors                  261728
Clusters count                 32720
Free clusters                  32716
First sector                       0
FAT first sector                 128
FAT sectors count                256
First cluster sector             384
Root directory cluster             5
Volume state                  0x0000
FATs count                         1
Drive number                    0x80
Allocated space                   0%
```

Similarly, exfatprogs comes with `dump.exfat`:

```
$ dump.exfat /tmp/exfat.img
exfatprogs version : 1.1.0
-------------- Dump Boot sector region --------------
Volume Length(sectors):                 262144
FAT Offset(sector offset):              128
FAT Length(sectors):                    256
Cluster Heap Offset (sector offset):    384
Cluster Count:                          32720
Root Cluster (cluster offset):          5
Volume Serial:                          0x765cf1c4
Sector Size Bits:                       9
Sector per Cluster bits:                3

----------------- Dump Root entries -----------------
Volume entry type:                      0x3
Volume label:
Volume label character count:           0
Bitmap entry type:                      0x81
Bitmap start cluster:                   2
Bitmap size:                            4090
Upcase table entry type:                0x82
Upcase table start cluster:             3
Upcase table size:                      5836

---------------- Show the statistics ----------------
Cluster size:                           4096
Total Clusters:                         32720
Free Clusters:                          32716
```

Comment: It seems **fsck.fat** gives me all the details I need. And it is present even on LiveCD installers, so very conveniently available when needed. I did not expect such a tool to provide these FAT details, so I neglected to check what the **-v** verbose flag gives me. Extra point for the **-n** flag in your example! Which is another detail I would have ignored. I did use mtools at the time I was triple-booting my 486DX2 with DRDOS, OS/2 and FreeBSD. And I completely have forgotten about it. Never knew it can provide these filesystem details. @user1686 your thorough answer is much appreciated!